# String Resources or JSON to populate SQLite Database on application start?

Tags: android, json, database, sqlite, android-recyclerview

Currently, I have three `string-arrays` in my `String Resources` that hold information I need for the application to start and function. These arrays need to be kept in order as `string-array` A position 5 corresponds to `string-array` B position 5 and so on.

This doesn't seem great as it can be error prone and not extensible if I want to add 100 new datapoints - so I have been looking into using a JSON file to store the data which seems to be better.

My problem: I have a `Recycler View` that is populated with data from my `String Resources`. Each item in the `Recycler View` is different, so the first view will take information from the first entry in `string-array` A, B and C and continue through each `view` in the `Recycler View`.

Is it better to create a JSON file that collects and groups the data so corresponding data is kept together? As well as reading this file into my SQLite database and create a cursor object that will populate my `Recycler View` and allow for some other database related activities later on in my application? From what I can tell it is.

Is this a viable solution to my problem?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to store JSON in a database, Sqlite probably isn't what you want. Look at Realm library, at least

Comment: Try using the the new Room architectural component , makes persisting your data easy and makes your code cleaner. So each of your arrays will be an Entity , follow this link for more info on how to achieve such https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html